# Fixing a WCF Deserialization Error

Tags: wcf, tcp, app-config

The error I get is the following:

> Maximum number of items that can be serialized or deserialized in an
>   object graph is 65536. Change the object graph or increase the
>   MaxItemsInObjectGraph quota.

Here is my app.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <netTcpBinding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IClusterControllerService">
                    <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
                </binding>
                <binding name="NetTcpBinding_IClusterManagementService">
                    <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" />
                </binding>

            </netTcpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint 
                address="some_address"
                binding="netTcpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IClusterControllerService"
                contract="ClusterControllerService.IClusterControllerService"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IClusterControllerService"
                behaviorConfiguration="BigObjectGraphBehavior">
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint 
                address="some_address"
                binding="netTcpBinding" 
                bindingConfiguration="NetTcpBinding_IClusterManagementService"
                contract="ClusterManagementService.IClusterManagementService"
                name="NetTcpBinding_IClusterManagementService"
                behaviorConfiguration="BigObjectGraphBehavior">
            </endpoint>
        </client>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="BigObjectGraphBehavior">
                    <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

It seems the maxItemsInObjectGraph settings isn't taking effect.
Is there another place I have to set this setting?

Comment: Check at client side generated app.config. Is it reflecting there?

Comment: Where do I find this? (I'm pretty new to WCF.)

Comment: At client application where you have added reference, there would be one app.config generated, there you can check this property

Answer (score 1):

Your config seems to be correct.

This settings can be set on client side and on server side. Also Check the source of this error (if IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults is true on server, exceptions are returned to the client)

Here is the sample config for this behavior.

```
//server side
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="LargeServiceBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>

//client side
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="LargeEndpointBehavior">
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

If you spin up your endpoint on our client dynamically (with ChannelFactory), you have to set the MaxItemsInObjectGraph property by hand.

```
foreach ( var operation in channelFactory.Endpoint.Contract.Operations )  
{  
    var behavior = operation.Behaviors.Find() as DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior;  
    if ( behavior != null )  
    {  
        behavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 2147483647;      
    }  
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I will check this answer tomorrow morning.